# Creating a Method in C# that traverses HTML document and extracts content based on a query, i.e Custom HTML Crawler

Tags: c#, data-structures, nodes, tree-traversal, html-content-extraction

I created a program that parses each one of the elements of an HTML Document. It saves it in a Tree strcuture(unbalanced tree).

```cs
public class Attribute
{
    public string? Key { get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
    public Attribute() {}
    public Attribute(string key, string value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
public class Node 
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    public Node(string tag)
    {
        Tag = tag;
        Attributes = new List<Attribute>();
        Children = new List<Node>();
        Content = "";
    }
}
```

This is the tree node structure.

---

*There were some constraints to the assignment such as **prohibition of Dictionaries, Queues, Hash tables, LinkedList etc. except for List, as well as HtmlAgilityPack or any library**. They could be used only if we create them ourselves. This is the reason behind using List and having distinct class for it.*

---

Here is the example HTML Document on which i should perform queries:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <p>Text1</p>
    <p>Text2</p>
    <p id='p3'>Text3</p>
    <div>
        <div>Text4</div>
        <p>Text5</p>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id='table2'>
        <tr>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>44</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="http://https://www.w3schools.com" src="img_girl.bmp">w3schools</a>
    <img src="img_girl.bmp" />
</body>
</html>
```

The program should extract content from the HTML document based on queries:
(These are all user inputs in the Console)

- PRINT `//` - extracts every text content from the document.
- PRINT `//html/body/p` -> Outputs: "Text1", "Text2", "Text3"
- PRINT `//html/body/table/tr/td` -> Outputs: "11", "22", "33", "44"
- PRINT `//html/body/p[2]` -> Outputs: "Text2";
- PRINT `//html/body/*[@id='table2']` -> Outputs: "33", "44"
- PRINT `//html/body/p[@id='p3']` -> извежда: 'Text3'.
- PRINT `//html/body/table[@id='table2']/tr[2]/td` -> извежда: "44"

Basically, the program should be a simpler version of XPath.

This is my traversal function:

```
private List<string> Traverse(Node node, string[] segments, int index)
{

    List<string> matches = new List<string>();
    if (node == null) return matches;

    if (index + 1 >= segments.Length)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Content))
        {
            matches.Add(node.Content);
        }
        foreach (Node child in node.Children)
        {
            matches.AddRange(Traverse(child, segments, index));
        }
        return matches;
    }
    string segment = segments[index];

    if (segment.Contains("*"))
    {
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            matches.AddRange(Traverse(child, segments, index + 1));
        }
    }
    else if (segment.Contains("@"))
    {
        int attributeStart = segment.IndexOf('@');
        int attributeEnd = segment.IndexOf('=');
        if (attributeStart != -1 && attributeEnd != -1)
        {
            string attributeName = segment.Substring(attributeStart + 1, attributeEnd - attributeStart - 1);
            string attributeValue = segment.Substring(attributeEnd + 2, segment.Length - attributeEnd - 4);

            foreach (var child in node.Children)
            {
                if (child.Attributes.Any(attr => attr.Key == attributeName && attr.Value == attributeValue))
                {
                    matches.AddRange(Traverse(child, segments, index + 1));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid attribute format");
        }
    }
    else if (segment.Contains("["))
    {
        int indexStart = segment.IndexOf("[");
        int indexEnd = segment.IndexOf("]");
        if (indexStart != -1 && indexEnd != -1)
        {
            string indexValue = segment.Substring(indexStart + 1, indexEnd - indexStart - 1);
            if (int.TryParse(indexValue, out int indexNum))
            {
                if (indexNum >= 0 && indexNum < node.Children.Count)
                {
                    matches.AddRange(Traverse(node.Children[indexNum], segments, index + 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Invalid index: {indexNum}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Invalid index value: {indexValue}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid index format");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {

            if (segments[index + 1] == child.Tag)
            {
                matches.AddRange(Traverse(child, segments, index + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

So at the last else statement it used to be segment instead of segments[index + 1]:

```cs
//...
foreach (var child in node.Children)
{
   if (segments[index + 1] == child.Tag)
    {
        matches.AddRange(Traverse(child, segments, index + 1));
    }
}
//...
```

This change fixed the problem when I write `//html/body` and it outputs nothing, whereas it should output every text content of the body.

But doing it this way does now allow me to search for specific elements such as `//html/body/p[1]`.

When the function reaches the else statement and traverses through the children of the node (`node.Children`)
`segments[index + 1]`
does not actually equal Node child, so the next level does not get traversed properly.
Then leaves the foreach loop and `return matches` gets executed with no content.

If somebody is able to understand my logic and help me fix the problem.

Comment: You might want to look at the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) NuGet. It has this kind of functionality built in.

Comment: Yes, i have looked it up but it is part of the constraints that i mention above. Thank you for the idea though.

Comment: Oops missed that. Sorry. I edited the question to make that clearer. Feel free to roll back the changes if that doesn't work for you.